# Power amplifier DC and AC current adding

Tags: amplifier, bjt, small-signal

Here is my simple power amplifier:

[image]

I need an explanation how the summary DC+AC current will behave on Probe2 and on Probe3 for positive and negative voltage swing of the signal in the amplifier input? How AC part of the amplified signal affects the Q3-Q4 constant current source DC current value? Up yellow box - Probe2, Bottom - Probe 3.

The output graph: red - output, blue - Q6 base

[image]

Comment: I still think you should use multisim for this and look at the waveforms and present those waveforms that you don't understand so that people can provide help. Also you need to clarify which yellow data box applies to which probe. Is there anything confusing you in the numbers for the yellow boxes?

Comment: @Andy aka I check the yellow boxes, but what waveforms to present for voltage (between probe2 and 3 to ground?) or for current (so I need add resistors to points for probe2 and probe3)?

Comment: Do you know how to run a transient analysis in multisim?

Comment: @Andy aka Yes of course.

Comment: Try probing voltages to produce a transient waveform. I don’t use multisim so I can’t really say much else.

Comment: @Andy aka I add the graph, red - output, blue - Q6 base voltage. For voltage there is no difference what probe to use.

Comment: That's entirely what I'd expect to see for this type of amplifier so... what is your question? BTW, where did you get the schematic from?

Comment: @Andy aka The question is how do AC signal on probe2/probe3 for positive/negative input swing affects the constant DC current from Q3-Q4 current source - AC adds to DC or AC is substracted from DC? Schematics got somewhere from network.

Comment: AC swing at Q5 base increase/decrease the Ic5 current in the rhythm of an input signal. Increases in Ic5 current (Q5 lowers his  "resistance" of the collector-emitter path) causes that the larger part of a Q4 current is now flowing into Q5 than to Q6 base. But if Q5 current decreases the larger part of a Q4 current will now flow into the Q6 base.

Comment: AC both adds and subtracts to the DC current but only a small amount. Q4 will be producing a constant DC value and Q5 is taking that DC value and trying to modulate that value with a tiny bit of success. If Q4 was a perfect solid constant current generator then it makes no difference in your circuit above because you have negative feedback ensuring that the signal voltage on the probe is what is needed to produce the right output voltage.

Comment: @Andy aka Great, but last words about "it makes no difference in your circuit..." I can't understand.

Comment: Because your power amp has negative feedback to Q2 from the output hence it acts like a regulator and controls all the signal p-p voltages within (inside) the loop.

Comment: @MaxMil You write, "Here is my simple power amplifier:"  Did you design this particular amplifier? If so, I'm just looking over the output stage and would like to ask a question or two about your thinking there. (Before considering answering any other question you may have.)

Comment: @jonk I don't design that amplifier. I took that schematic from free samples in network and look for help in places where I can't understand something. "My simple amplifier" only means that I work with that schematic and not mean that I'm an author of that. About output stage I can say that it class B part that works by modulation with all other stages. That method you may see in many schematics based on op-amps where power rails of op-amp connected to resistors that loaded with power BJT's that work in Class B. An op-amp modulates the signal which is amplified by an output stage.

Comment: @MaxMil The output stage is less thermally stable than if they had connected the collectors through a different path. I feel it's not a good choice. It would work, of course. But it's not so good a design choice, broadly speaking. There were a few other details I wanted to ask about. But since you didn't design it, I won't trouble you with the questions.

Comment: @MaxMil I still can't actually tell what those two curves are. It looks to me like probe 2 and probe 3 are hooked to the same place on the schematic. But the curves on the "scope" are clearly different and so that merely means I'm not understanding something that you probably understand. Perhaps you could add some words to help. Also, the scope appears to be discussing voltage. But your question seems to be about current? Not sure here, again.

Comment: @jonk Yes, I ask about current, but the graph is for voltage. But that graph was enough to upper commenter to answer the question about currents. The question was how would be DC Q-point current value going from Q3-Q4 current source combined with AC value of audio signal. If you have what to add write and it may be a good addition to about information.

Comment: @MaxMil I'll give it a shot. Ask further, if I missed the mark.

Comment: @jonk You say that output stage is less thermal stability, hmm? May you present alternative solution for an output stage? I find that used here have very high efficiency because of there is no any initial current for Q-point state and the out BJT's must be cold when there is no audio signal applied to input.

Comment: @MaxMil I don't mean "hotter" when I say "not as thermally stable." Those are not the same meanings.

Comment: @jonk Ok, I know that it's not the same. I only print info what I know. If you have an alternate solution for more stability and using class B I'll glad to see that.

Comment: @MaxMil One question at a time, I think. The Sziklai stage you have will do a job. And getting into a protracted discussion about changing it is really a different question, I think. There are also possible other problems having to do with oscillation and damping those out (adding a zero) that could also be added to your solution. And that would again be another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question. But I have an idea about it, given the "arrows" I see added to the schematic and added to by your question, which talks about the "positive and negative voltage swing" at the input.

I think you are wondering about what happens to the current source's current as it flows towards and is then sunk by the \$Q_5\$ VAS collector.

In general, if you accept the idea that feedback in the entire amplifier circuit will do what is necessary to ensure that the \$Q_5\$ VAS does the "right job," then the explanation isn't complex. But if you need to walk all the way around the entire closed loop system and look at each detail of ***how*** the design, plus feedback, operates on a DC and AC level (the feedback itself has an AC and DC perspective that achieve different things simultaneously), then your question would take more time to answer.

So let me just simplify things for now and ignore a careful discussion of the entire circuit, because I think if you were asking for that perhaps you are asking a far too broad of a question. So I'll assume you just want to know about the current source's current from the source at \$Q_4\$ to the sink at \$Q_5\$.

---

\$Q_4\$ is, as I think you know, arranged to provide a current source of about \$2\:\text{mA}\$. (Interestingly, this is also the current flowing in the two diodes behind \$Q_4\$ that bias it.) Given the gain in the Sziklai pairs used in both quadrants for the output stage, that may be about right (though I think it is perhaps just a little bit "thin" given the \$33\:\text{V}\$ rails and the power output potential for that.) This current then flows downward towards the \$Q_5\$ collector, where whatever remains is then sunk.

So that's about it, really:

1. \$2\:\text{mA}\$ is sourced out of \$Q_4\$.
2. If the upper Sziklai quadrant requires some base drive current for recombination, then this is removed from the \$2\:\text{mA}\$ before it flows through the two diodes towards \$Q_5\$'s collector.
3. If the lower Sziklai quadrant requires some base drive current for recombination, then this is added to the approximately \$2\:\text{mA}\$ that has now already proceeded through the two diodes on its way towards \$Q_5\$'s collector.
4. The \$Q_5\$ collector sinks the resulting net current, which will either be a little less than \$2\:\text{mA}\$ (if the upper quadrant required base current) or else a little more than \$2\:\text{mA}\$ (if the lower quadrant required base current) or else very close to \$2\:\text{mA}\$ if the output isn't sourcing or sinking current at the moment.

It's a pretty simple idea.

---

The whole point of the diff-pair at the input, and the feedback system both at DC (output fed directly back to the diff-pair) and AC (a divided portion fed back), is to cause \$Q_5\$'s collector to do exactly what is needed for the above to work successfully.

Comment: Very interesting and useful fo me. You absolutely right and fully understand me when wrote "But if you need to walk all the way around the entire closed loop system...". In first approximation the cosidering of all I need, but when the comments from different authors was added I found that it's not so easy to show all of that. I found that many users do not use that all in their projects. And how do you think is there so granular level really need for practical building of not very complex amplifiers? Or understanding of working principle of simple blocks will be enough?

Comment: @MaxMil The exact details involve a thorough understanding of each subsection of the circuit. But a designer for hobbyist work usually only needs to keep in mind the ***more important*** details and knows enough to ignore those that are ***less important.*** A commercial product will take a lot more into account and probably will have several different, carefully crafted front end pre-amplifiers targeting minimum noise for a variety of inputs, followed by opamps used in the middle sections, followed by a well-crafted output driver system from discretes.

Comment: @MaxMil The "level" of thinking required varies. Personally, I don't care about as many of the details that a professional designer of a commercial system will care about. And so I don't worry so much about them for what I might cobble up for personal use. What exactly do you need to know?

Comment: I want to know is it really need to know all about DC+AC signal components combining in an amplifiers like my or I only need to know about Q-point and that the AC signal modulates the DC Q-point when the signal applied? Is it really need to go deeper for non-professional amplifier construction?

Comment: @MaxMil You go as deep as you want to. Of course, you have to have the basics to start out. Or else you have nothing at all. But once you get the basics, the rest can happen if and when you want to worry more about it. If you want a walk through of your circuit, pose a separate question that specifically asks for an overview level walkthrough of the circuit. This would mean that I would ***not*** discuss the details of *why* a diff-pair works as it does, but I would discuss *what* it does for you. If that's something that would help.